# Помогите закончить задание!

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Написать программу вычисление н-го числа ряда Фибоначчи на языке PYTHON.
2. Должна быть возможность выполнить ряд действий не выходя из программы.
3. При вводе ненатурального числа, должно вывестись соответствующее послание, при этом программу можно выполнять по новой не выходя из неё.

Я всё сделал, кроме 3-го пункта. Помогите, пожалуйста, я в тупике. Вот код.

```
ok = 1
while ok == 1:
    n = input(" Введите натуральное число n, n >= 0 ")
    n = int(n)
    def fb(n):
        if n == 0: return 0
        elif n == 1: return 1
        else: return fb(n-1)+fb(n-2)
    print ("Номер" , n , "в скале Фибоначии - это число " , fb(n))
    ok = int(input(" Продолжить (1), закончить (0)" ))
```

Comment: Рекурсия для вычисления чисел Фибоначчи не самое удачное решение. Уже при n = 30 начинает тормозить. Если ввести 50, то ответа можно и не дождаться. И почему «скала»-то?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk0zUZW-U_M Вот посмотрите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто зациклите код запроса ввода числа и не выходите из цикла пока не получите нужный результат:

```
def fb(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    elif n == 1: return 1
    else: return fb(n-1)+fb(n-2)

ok = 1

while ok == 1:
    while True:
        n = input(" Введите натуральное число n, n >= 0 ")
        try:
            n = int(n)
            if n < 0:
                raise ValueError()
            break

        except ValueError:
            print("Введено не натуральное число")

    print("Номер", n, "в скале Фибоначии - это число", fb(n))
    ok = int(input(" Продолжить (1), закончить (0)"))
```

---

**UPD.** Добавил дополнительную проверку, что введенное число является целочисленным.

Если в `int` попадет строка не являющаяся целым числом, то функция выбросит исключения вида `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`, а раз код немного изменился то, для не натуральных чисел, выбрасываю это же исключение

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ ВАМ ЧЕЛОВЕЧЕСКОЕ СПАСИБО!

Comment: @Halfpizods, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Не работает, если я ввожу ненатуральное число 2.3 :Р

Comment: @Эникейщик, поправил :)